# Launch Windows Command Line Prompt with Custom Environment Variables

Tags: windows, environment-variables

This guide will help to launch Windows Command Prompt with custom environment variables. Sometimes we need to launch command line with custom environment variables. This guide will create a shortcut to launch set custom environment variables.

Answer (score 11):

Even though it is an old question but still I find lots of people querying about it. Basically,

**Our primary goal is to Launch Command Line Prompt with Custom Environment Variables and PREVENT command line from auto exiting!**.

We'll using here **/k** switch of **cmd**. You can read more about it by typing `cmd /?` in command prompt. I'm also pasting its snapshot to show the relevant part where it mentions the word *remains* which means persistent with the session. Here is the snapshot.

[image]

---

### Method 1: Launch Command Line with Inline Environment Declarations

In this method you need to create a shortcut (*or run from RUN command*) with your custom environment variables using **&&** operator. Here this && denotes AND analogy that we studied in programming.

1. Go to your Windows Desktop.
2. Right click on the desktop and click on **New Shortcut**
3. [image: Snapshot 1 of 2 of a typical shortcut with inline variables]
4. Don't miss the ending **"** quotes. [image: Snapshot 2 of 2 of a typical shortcut with inline variables]
5. In the shortcut paste the following line. To demonstrate an example I'm here setting up some custom environment parameters to launch my ruby enabled command line. `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "set RUBYOPT=-E utf-8 && set SSL_CERT_File=c:\Ruby22\cacert.pem"`. Please note that we writing the command environments in a **Single Line** by using **&&** operator. You can repeat && any number of times you want. Now save the Shortcut with any name and double click it to see the environment set.

---

### Method 2: Setting Up Custom Environment Paths from a different batch file (.bat)

1. Create a batch file with any name. In this example we'll call it *launch.bat* and save it to *c:\launches\launch.bat*. [image]
2. Now Create a shortcut *(like explained in method 1)* or run it via *Windows + R* command with the following parameters.
3. `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "c:\launches\launch.bat"`.
4. [image: Launching Command Line from Environment Variables from a different batch file]

   5. [image: Launching Command Line from Environment Variables from a different batch file after launch]

Comment: Excellent answer. It's rare to see a detailed manual with screenshots :) You can validate that variable(s) were set by `@echo %somevariable%`

Answer (score 3):

In most cases the local environment is passed down from parent to child processes, so all you need to do is set some environment variables and start a new command prompt.  Make a bat file and add this for Windows Shell:

```
SET myVar=blarblarblar
start cmd
```

Or for Powershell:

```
SET myVar=blarblarblar
start Powershell
```